# Remote Control for Android Smart Tv in Java

Tags: android, remote-access, smart-tv

I used the ConnectSDK for android and it's find my Android Smart Tv in Network but when I click on the device name trying to connect with it. it's just simply connect and did not pair with it...
The pairing is a must because the android Smart Tv did not give you full access without pairing.
I can only open Netflix from my custom tv remote without pairing it with Android Smart TV.
So I want to know that how would I pair with Android Smart Tv and control with custom remote
I want to create smart tv remote like this one [Universal Tv remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=codematics.universal.tv.remote.control)

Answer (score 0):

For android TV,you can use Adb shell commands for remote control and app launching as well.
Connect SDK lib is not support all the commands for android TV.
If you want to implement Adb shell then I can share you some references.